Flutter camera - handle the pictures orientation without forced rotation
My colleague and I heve been struggling a lot with pictures orientation using the
flutter camera package
What we try to achieve is a native OS camera behaviour, where the picture taken will always be "naturally" oriented regardless of the device orientation when taking the picture.
When taking a picture of a tree, we want the saved pciture to have the leaves at the top, and the roots à the bottom.


Has anyone achieved this without having to rotate the image on save ? Using (maybe) the right combination of :
lockCaptureOrientation method
and
unlockCaptureOrientation method
Using later rotation or exif editing has proven to be unreliable, because the behaviour are very diffretn from Android to iOs.
And I cannot belive that the pugin does not handle this natively, given the importance of this issue.
What are we missing ? :)
Thanks a lot for your help
